# Using an href tag in Exception message- JSP

Tags: jsp, exception, href

This Exception is going in Error.jsp . The message is correctly going into this page, but the part of  here  does not appear. What is the problem?

```
 <%
  if (x== 5) {
     throw new Exception("For login press <a href="LoginForm.jsp">here</a> ");
  }
 %>
```

Comment: You could try using this instead.   throw new Exception("For login press <a href='LoginForm.jsp'>here</a> ");